# Bugsnag from a browser: is there a way I can add my own header?

Tags: javascript, bugsnag

Using `"@bugsnag/browser": "7.5.6"`

I have configured `bugsnag` to send requests to a custom endpoint by doing:

```
Bugsnag.start({
  ...
  autoTrackSessions: false,
  endpoints: {
    notify: 'htts://custom-notify-url.example.com',
    sessions: 'https://bugsnag-sessions.example.com', 
  },
  onError: async function (event: any) {
    console.log("bugsnag error event", event);
  },
})
```

This works, and sends requests to `custom-notify-url.example.com`

But I need the bugsnag requests to have a specific header.

Is it possible to configure bugsnag so that it applies a custom header to the notification `POST` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugsnag's error reporting API, which is what all of their libraries use, doesn't support passing custom fields in the header. If you are ultimately forwarding events to notify.bugsnag.com, you will not be able to have a custom header - you also can't override the header for a custom endpoint.